# Script filter very slow

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query with script, and it took me very slow time to execute(15s). The problem is script, I have to take summarize few columns and compare with number. Are there anything to improve the performance? or are there another solution to replace script in this case

```
{  
   "size":0,
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "range":{  
                  "date_sec":{  
                     "gte":1423155600,
                     "lte":1543165200
                  }
               }
            },
            {  
               "range":{  
                  "time_sec":{  
                     "gte":32400,
                     "lte":82800
                  }
               }
            },
            {  
               "terms":{  
                  "id_stores":[  
                     2317,
                     2210,
                     .... over 1000 more......
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggs":{  
      "current_period3":{  
         "filter":{  
            "bool":{  
               "must":[  
                  {  
                     "terms":{  
                        "table_type":[  
                           3
                        ]
                     }
                  },
                  {  
                     "range":{  
                        "date_sec":{  
                           "gte":1483203600,
                           "lte":1543165200
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "aggs":{  
            "id_stores":{  
               "terms":{  
                  "field":"id_stores",
                  "size":1000
               },
               "aggs":{  
                  "area_type":{  
                     "terms":{  
                        "field":"area_type"
                     },
                     "aggs":{                          
                        "result_1":{  
                           "filter":{  
                              "script":{  
                                 "script":{  
                                    "inline":"doc.goinside.value == 1 && doc.buy.value == 1 && doc.sale_time.value != '' && (doc.zone1.value+doc.zone2.value+doc.zone3.value) > 0",
                                    "lang":"painless"
                                 }
                              }
                           },
                           "aggs":{  
                              "result_1":{  
                                 "sum":{  
                                    "script":{  
                                       "inline":"doc.zone1.value+doc.zone2.value+doc.zone3.value",
                                       "lang":"painless"
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        },
                        .............. over 1000 filter more ...................
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The results always above 15s, my elasticsearch is window os, RAM 16GB, CPU i5-3570 3.4ghz

```
{
    "took": 14980,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 45869315,
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {        
        "current_period3": {
            "doc_count": 3128225,
            "id_stores": {
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                "buckets": [
                    {
}
]
```

Comment: You are using multilevel aggregations (i.e. aggs inside aggs) with depth of 3+ and each level has script. I think you should rethink on the mapping structure and what additional data you can index so that you can avoid calculations in script. You should avoid using script as it will lead to performance degradation which you are already facing.

Comment: Another note is why 1000+ filters are required?

Comment: thanks for answer. 1000+ mean I have many type of data with different condition. I need a lot of data return